# Is there an alternative to Android's ViewOverlay?

Tags: android, view, overlay

Android's [`ViewOverlay`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay.html%20ViewOverlay) allows easy overlaying of `Drawable`s over a conventional view element without having to interfere with the layout, but it is only available since API 18 (and as far as I can see, there's no compatibility layer, that backports this).

What would be the easiest alternative for an older API level (specifically: 15) to overlay a `Drawable` over a view element without modifying the layout? In my case, it would be enough to deal with a single `Drawable`; I don't need to replicate support for multiple `Drawable`s that the new overlay API allows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `FrameLayout`'s foreground attribute?
`FrameLayout`'s foreground is drawn over it's contents. And this works with API level 15.

In your xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/your_drawable">

    ...
    Your contents.
    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

Or in your source code:

```
frameLayout.setForeground(drawable);
```